# one to many queries

Tags: php, sql, mysql

Alright, I've just finished normalizing a table. What I didn't really consider when I was doing it is that I now have a one to many relationship... being that my sql knowledge is very, very limited I'm not really sure how to approach this.

I tried grouping by the foreign key, but it only returns the last matching result and I want to return both of them as well as any results where there is only one fk.

Desired Output:

```
   Site         Found On             Score
   example.com  sourece1, source2    400
   example.net  sourece1             23
   example.org  sourece2             23
```

Where:
siteScoring.url = found on
siteScoring.votes = score
media.file_url = site

Comment: Showing us your schema and the desired output would help a lot. Even better would be DDL and inserts to create a data set.

Comment: For example.com, do source1 and source2 each have a score of 400 or is that the combined score of the `Found on` rows?

Comment: It is total score, should have clarified that.

Comment: Sorry, it's not clear to me what table.column I need to use for the site and found on output values.  The comma list isn't a problem, just need to know where to get the data.

Comment: Ah, meant:

media.file_url = site
siteScoring.url = found on
siteScoring.votes = score

Comment: @Eric: thx, what relates a `MEDIA.file_url` to a `SITESCORING` record?

Comment: Please provide actual data that might be in the table

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using MySQL 5+ you can use `GROUP_CONCAT(source)` (in the select clause) to create the `Found On` column in your current `GROUP BY` query

EDIT: my mistake it's MySQL 4.1+: [`group_concat`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat)

Answer (score 1):

Psuedo SQL till details arrive:

```
  SELECT t.file_url,
         CONCAT_WS(',', ss.url) 'Found On',
         SUM(ss.votes)
    FROM MEDIA t
    JOIN SITESCORING ss ON ss. = m. --just missing JOIN criteria
GROUP BY t.file_url
```